# How to merge two dataframes based on file name?

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a dictionary of dataframes with keys in the form `"Sample_X_####celsius"`. Each dataframe is structured like this:

| displacement | force |
| --- | --- |
| values | values |
| values | values |
| values | values |

I also have an additional dataframe with three columns structured like this:

| label | width | thickness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sample_1_200celsius | 11 | 222 |
| sample_1_300celsius | 12 | 223 |

How can I combine each row of the additional dataframe with the dataframe in the dictionary who's key corresponds to the "label" entry? My goal looks like this:

key: `sample_1_200celsius`

| displacement | force | label | width | thickness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| values | values | sample_1_200celsius | 11 | 222 |
| values | values |  |  |  |
| values | values |  |  |  |

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2])`. But are you sure you want a `concat` (so `label, width, thickness` are only non-empoty on the first row?), rather than a join with broadcasting to all rows? what is your intent, what do you want to do with the output df?

Comment: Possible duplicate, see [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: I don't quite understand what is *a dictionary of dataframes with keys in the form "Sample_X_####celsius"*.

Comment: @smci I can't concatenate because I have a ton of different files (300+). I need a way for only one row from the additional dataframe to be "matched" to each file in the dictionary who's key is the same as the label of that row.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh The keys match up with the "label" row of the additional dataframe is what I was trying to say there.

Comment: @aria39948 In the last dataframe of you posted, what's the value of `label`, `width`, `thickness` column of the last two rows.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh No value there-- I want to take only one row from the 2nd dataframe and add  it to each instance of the first dataframe. So for the sample_1_200celsius first dataframe, it only gets the row of the second dataframe that contains "sample_1_200celsius".

Comment: You can do the concatenate/join if you do them at read-time. Or you could do it in batches of say 10. Really you need to go back and show us the read or load commands that imported these dfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dictionary and additional dataframe are `dictionary` and `df`, you can [**`concat()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the `dictionary` dataframes with the corresponding `df` row:

```py
for key in dictionary.keys():
    dfs = [dictionary[key], df.loc[df.label == key].reset_index(drop=True)]
    dictionary[key] = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

---

#### Full example

Given `dictionary` with dataframes for `sample_1_200celsius` and `sample_1_300celsius`:

```py
df200 = pd.DataFrame({'displacement': [1,2,3], 'values': [2,4,6]})
df300 = pd.DataFrame({'displacement': [30,20,10], 'values': [60,40,20]})
dictionary = {'sample_1_200celsius': df200, 'sample_1_300celsius': df300}
```

And additional dataframe `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['sample_1_200celsius','sample_1_300celsius'], 'width': [11,12], 'thickness': [222,223]})

#                  label  width  thickness
# 0  sample_1_200celsius     11        222
# 1  sample_1_300celsius     12        223
```

You can [**`concat()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) each `dictionary` dataframe with the corresponding row from `df` using `loc` indexing:

```py
for key in dictionary.keys():
    dfs = [dictionary[key], df.loc[df.label == key].reset_index(drop=True)]
    dictionary[key] = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

So then the `dictionary` values will be updated as desired:

```py
dictionary['sample_1_200celsius']

#    displacement  values                label  width  thickness
# 0             1       2  sample_1_200celsius   11.0      222.0
# 1             2       4                  NaN    NaN        NaN
# 2             3       6                  NaN    NaN        NaN
```

```py
dictionary['sample_1_300celsius']

#    displacement  values                label  width  thickness
# 0            30      60  sample_1_300celsius   12.0      223.0
# 1            20      40                  NaN    NaN        NaN
# 2            10      20                  NaN    NaN        NaN
```